# Why is the second parameter of std::assoc_laguerre an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

In C++17, a lot of special functions were added to the standard library. One function is the [associated Laguerre polynomials](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/assoc_laguerre). The second argument requires an `unsigned int`, but the [mathematical definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html) is valid for real numbers as well. Is there any reason that it's only limited to nonnegative integers? Is it simply due to the fact that binomial(n,k) is is easier/faster/simpler to calculate when n and k are both positive integers?

Comment: If this would be better suited for math.stackexchange, feel free to migrate it there instead.

Comment: To the extent that it's on-topic on any Stack Exchange site, it's best suited here. Though I think it's best off on the std-discussions mailing list. The history of C++ is definitely not suited for a Maths SE.

Comment: Incidentally I cannot believe that such arbitrary esoteric mathematical equations made it into the stdlib. What were they thinking?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: depends on your application domain. In physics and mechanical engineering, these functions are just functions, like `log()` and `sin()`. But, yes, you have a point. Normal persons who are neither physicists nor mechanical engineers have no idea what such functions are for. Nor should they have an idea. This observation would suggest omission from the standard library. One point, though: at the time, in 2003, the Fortran programming language was fading. C++ moves into Fortran's domain by including such functions, so this factor might have had something to do.

Comment: @thb Could be. Feels like scope creep to me though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walter E. Brown, father of special functions in C++, never explicitly answered your Laguerre question as far as I know. Nevertheless, when one reads [what Brown did write,](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1542.pdf) a likely motive grows clear:

> Many of the proposed Special Functions have definitions over some or all of the complex plane as well as over some or all of the real numbers. Further, some of these functions can produce complex results, even over real-valued arguments. The present proposal restricts itself by considering only real-valued arguments and (correspondingly) real-valued results.
>
> Our investigation of the alternative led us to realize that the complex landscape for the Special Functions is figuratively dotted with land mines. In coming to our recommendation, we gave weight to the statement from a respected colleague that “Several Ph.D. dissertations would [or could] result from efforts to implement this set of functions over the complex domain.” **This led us to take the position that there is insufficient prior art in this area to serve as a basis for standardization, and that such standardization would be therefore premature....**

Of course, you are asking about real numbers rather than complex, so I cannot prove that the reason is the same, but Abramowitz and Stegun (upon whose manual Brown's proposal was chiefly based) provide extra support to some special functions of integer order. Curiously, in chapter 13 of my copy of Abramowitz and Stegun, I see no extra support, so you have a point, don't you? Maybe Brown was merely being cautious, not wishing to push too much into the C++ standard library all at once, but there does not immediately seem to me to be any obvious reason why floating-point arguments should not have been supported in this case.

Not that I would presume to second-guess Brown.

As you likely know, you can probably use chapter 13 of Abramowitz and Stegun to get the effect you want without too much trouble. Maybe Brown himself would have said just this: you can get the effect you want without too much trouble. To be sure, one would need to ask Brown himself.

For information, Brown's proposal, earlier linked, explicitly refers the `assoc_laguerre` of C++ to Abramowitz and Stegun, sect. 13.6.9.

In summary, at the time C++ was first getting special-function support, caution was heeded. The library did not want to advance too far, too fast. It seems fairly probable that this factor chiefly accounts for the lack you note.

Answer (score 3):

I know for a fact that there was a great concern over real and perceived implementability.  Also, new library features have to justified.  Features have to be useful to more than one community. Integer order assoc_laguerre is the type physicists most often use.  A signed integer or real order was probably thought too abstract.  As it was, the special math functions barely made it into C++17.  I actually think part of the reason they got in was the perception that 17 was a light release and folks wanted to bolster it.

As we all know, there is no reason for the order parameter to be unsigned, or even integral for that matter.  The underlying implementation that I put in libstdc++ ( gcc) has a real order alpha.  Real order assoc_laguerre is useful in quadrature rules for example.

I might recommend making overloads for real order to the committee in addition to relaxing the unsigned integer to be signed.

Comment: Literally adding things to the standard for the sake of adding things, then! Shame!

Comment: I am a physicist who only uses fractional order associated Laguerre polynomials. It's the wavefunction of the 3D harmonic oscillator, a very common use case in physics.

Comment: @Lightness I agree adding just to add is a recipe for chaos.  On the other hand, making this extension requires no substantive change to the implementation and makes the thing more useful for more people.

Comment: @emsr Yep, tough line to draw and I for one am glad I don't have to draw it :)